# H1 makes space/gap between header and top of page

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where my h1 tags gets seperated from the top of my page - like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5etA7.png)

I'm still very new to HTML & CSS, so I'm asking for your help. Also, I DID look around to see other posts about this and I've tried ALOT, but i can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my CSS & HTML:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.header{
   background: url("../images/artboard1.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#logo {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1rem;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}
  a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 3rem;
}

.content_top {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 260px;
  padding: 4rem 0 8rem 0; }
  .sub_title, .under_title {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .sub_title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .logo_middle {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .under_title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

.content {
    background: url(../images/Untitled-2.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #0D0E12;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.projekter {
  background-color: #0D0E12;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Jakob Hoeg</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="header">
      <header>
        <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="images/logo_top.png" draggable="false"/>
        <nav>
          <a href="#">HJEM</a>
          <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
          <a href="#">KONTAKT</a>
        </nav>

        <div class="content_top">
          <h4 class="sub_title">HEY, MIT NAVN ER</h4>
          <img class="logo_middle" src="images/logo_big.png" draggable="false"/>
          <h4 class="under_title">MULTIMEDIEDESIGN STUDERENDE</h4>
        </div>
      </header>

    </div>

    <section class="content">
      <div id="content_cont">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="projekter">
      <div id="projekter">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to look into reset CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heh, it's a very interesting effect - "margin collapsing".
`h1` has default `margin-top`.

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to
>   separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first
>   child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height,
>   min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block
>   from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse.
>   The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

To solve this problem add `padding-top` to container or replace header `margin-top` with `padding-top`. Also can set `h1` `margin-top` to 0.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

Comment: Thank you! This pretty much solved the problem. However, I looked into a reset.css and i made one with a h1 with a margin of 0, which sorted the problem!

Comment: Ok. Your question reminded as I searched for a solution to this problem a few years ago =)

Comment: Haha, yea. Well, all i can do is practice, right? :-)

Comment: @Jakob Exactly.

Answer (score 4):

could you add this style. It'll works.

```
#content_cont h1 { margin-top:0; }
```

Comment: This works! But why can't i just make a h1 with a margin-top of 0? Why doens't that seem to work, and why do i have to write #content_cont? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Normally without reset CSS the browser takes default spacing around 10px. So we need to reset the HTML tags. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

Try not to set width and height for every objects. As other answers say you can move objects using margin in css. But my concern is adding unnecesary styles like width and height 100% for html, body, content and ... bringing some conflict to your design.

Comment: Allright. For the HTML & Body, i was looking at a tutorial where he did that aswell - but I'll mess around and see what I can do. Thanks for the comment.